# Use code in a file as content of a SAS macro variable

Tags: file, import, sas

I have a series of files, each containing SQL code.
I'd like to use SAS to run passthrough queries using that SQL.
Since those files are changing often I just want an automated way to keep SAS synched up with these files.
I'm thinking that if I could import the SQL file and put it into a macro variable, then I could just use the macro within my SAS passthrough and everything would be in synch.
But I wouldn't know how to read the external SQL in anything other than a SAS dataset, which wouldn't make a lot of sense to start with...
Example:
sqlcode.sql

```
select *
from table1
```

In SAS:

```
/*Somehow read sqlcode.sql into a macro variable sassql*/

proc sql;
connect to netezza (SERVER=MYSERVER DATABASE=MYDBS);

execute (
&sassql.

) by netezza;

;
quit;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT-new answer that actually works:

You could read your entire query into a macro variable through a data step, but you'd be limited to 32,767 total characters in the query, as that is the most a character variable would hold.

I'd suggest using a data step to read your query line by line, putting the entire query into a temp file, and including the temp file using `%include`:

```
filename query temp;
data _null_;
  infile 'C:\My Documents\sql query.sql' end=eof truncover;
  input @1 line $32767.;
  file query;
  if _n_=1 then put  'proc sql;
                      connect to netezza (SERVER=MYSERVER DATABASE=MYDBS);
                      execute (';
  put                 line;
  if eof then put    ') by netezza;
                      quit;';
run;
%include query / source2;
filename query clear;
```

Here, the temp file is "query", thedata step reads the sql file line by line and outputs each line to the temp file.

Comment: %include is used to run an external piece of SAS code, it doesn't work in this situation. Al least, I wasn't able to get it to work.

Comment: @ADJ You're right, my initial answer didn't work because it was passing `%include...` to the database. The updated answer above should work.

Comment: Actually, you weren't passing `%include` to the database - not really.  You can use SAS macro variables in that context and it works fine.  `%include` is just oddly picky about when it works, for some reason probably related to 1970s mainframes.

Answer (score 0):

Read in your files with datasteps, then follow those up with sql select-into queries like this:

```
data query_text;
    infile 'sql query.sql';
    input line $1000;
run;

proc sql;
    select * from query_text into :sassql separated by ' ';
quit;
```

The whole read-in file will be dumped to a macro variable.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this issue a few times so I wrote my own macro version of `%include` called `%include_file()`.  Looking over my notes it should work although if the file you are including contains macro tokens you may need to adjust the macro quoting function.

It will work on a file of any size (as it reads it one line at a time and doesn't try and store the whole file to a variable).

Simply call it like this:

```
proc sql;
connect to netezza (SERVER=MYSERVER DATABASE=MYDBS);
execute (
  %include_file(iFileName=c:\mypath\mysasfile.sas);
) by netezza;
;
quit;
```

The code is below.  I suggest putting it in your macro autocall library:

```
%macro include_file(iFileName=);
  %local filrf rc fid rc2;

  %let filrf=myfile2;

  %let rc=%sysfunc(filename(filrf, &iFileName, , lrecl=32767));
  %let fid=%sysfunc(fopen(&filrf,i,32767,b));

  %if &fid > 0 %then %do;
    %let rc = %sysfunc(fread(&fid));
    %do %while(&rc eq 0);  
      /* NOTE THE STACKED COMMANDS BECAUSE WE ARE RETURNING THE CONTENTS OF MACRO VAR C HERE AND DONT WANT WHITESPACE */
      %let rc2=%sysfunc(fget(&fid,c,32767));%quote(&c)%let rc = %sysfunc(fread(&fid)); 
    %end;
  %end;
  %else %do;
    %put C &fid %sysfunc(sysmsg());
  %end;
  %let rc=%sysfunc(fclose(&fid));
  %let rc=%sysfunc(filename(filrf));
%mend;
```